# PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID Missing From PayPal Response

Tags: php, paypal

When sending payments through to PayPal via Express Checkout, I'm getting success responses but something's clearly not working as I'm not being sent back any proper transaction details and the money isn't being moved between accounts.

For example (this is a sandbox test); When I call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, I get:

```
[TOKEN] => EC%2d4JJ53861VP761820C
[TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d12%2d08T13%3a10%3a45Z
[CORRELATIONID] => c460e7e7bcfd5
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 109%2e0
[BUILD] => 18308778
```

But that's it. As you can see, all the PAYMENTREQUEST lines, most importantly PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID are missing but the ACK reports success.

The users checks out, SetExpressCheckout runs and if successful the user gets redirected from my site to PayPal, logs in, can view the items they are paying for with the correct prices, hits "Pay" and is redirected back to my site where the DoExpressCheckoutPayment line fires off with their token and PayerID. Nothing errors at any point and everything looks right.

I assume I'm missing a key step here but I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to set a recurring payments?

Comment: No, it was a single one off payment. "Sale" in PayPal language.

Answer (score 0):

The typical situation, you find the issue 30 seconds after posting.

The issue was that I accidentally set the "METHOD" within the variable that I kept sending back to PayPal, this meant that in the second instance I was overriding the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call with SetExpressCheckout instead.